# My C# Systemd service show inactive(dead) after starting

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu, systemd

1. I made a .sh file to run my c# service.
2. Inside sh file folder setup is

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> /usr/bin/dotnet /opt/aid-dotnet/publish/IncidentDetection.dll
> ```

3. And My Service file is in

> `/etc/systemd/system`

4. Name of service is sharpradar.service

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=CSHARPSERVICE
>
> [Service]
> Type=forking
> ExecStart= dotnet IncidentDetection.dll
> WorkingDirectory=/opt/aid-dotnet/netcoreapp3.1/
> Restart=on-abort
> RemainAfterExit=yes
> KillSignal=SIGINT
> SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
> Environment=AMQP_USERNAME=test
> Environment=AMQP_PASSWORD=test123654
> Environment=AMQP_HOST=192.168.2.181
> Environment=AID_ID=3
> Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
> Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

5. But when I start my service I get this message

> ```
>  systemctl status sharpradar.service
>
> ● cshradar.service - CSHARPSERVICE
>      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/cshradar.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2023-01-25 15:57:46 IST; 1h 22min ago
>     Process: 20016 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet IncidentDetection.dll (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Jan 25 15:56:37 aidmain-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 dotnet-example[20016]: 01/25/2023 15:56:37 [INF] Connected to
>   configuration request queue.
> Jan 25 15:56:37 aidmain-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 dotnet-example[20016]: 01/25/2023 15:56:37 [INF] Connected to
>   congfiguraiton queue for AID_ID = 3.
> Jan 25 15:56:37 aidmain-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 dotnet-example[20016]: 01/25/2023 15:56:37 [INF] Requesting
>   configuration for AID_ID = 3.
> Jan 25 15:56:37 aidmain-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 dotnet-example[20016]: 01/25/2023 15:56:37 [INF] Received new
>   configuration.
> Jan 25 15:56:37 aidmain-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 dotnet-example[20016]: 01/25/2023 15:56:37 [INF]
>   {"printReceivedData":false,"ruleConstraints":{"SpeedTooHigh":{"MaximumAllowedSpeed":15>
> Jan 25 15:56:37 aidmain-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 dotnet-example[20016]: 01/25/2023 15:56:37 [INF] Succesfully reloaded
>   configuration.
> Jan 25 15:56:38 aidmain-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 dotnet-example[20016]: 01/25/2023 15:56:38 [INF] Start waiting for
>   data.
> Jan 25 15:56:38 aidmain-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 systemd[1]: Started CSHARPSERVICE.
> Jan 25 15:57:46 aidmain-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 systemd[1]: cshradar.service: Succeeded.
> Jan 25 15:57:46 aidmain-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 systemd[1]: Stopped CSHARPSERVICE.
> ```

6. The service becomes dead when my C# service wait for data and get freeze at http request.
7. But if I run this code directly inside tmux then it run properly, but not with systemd, I am unable to understand this.
8. I am attaching screenshot of running example using tmux(Sorry for attacing this screenshot because its not getting formatted on stack overflow)

[image: Successfully Run Using tmux]

9. I tried multiple different aspects to run but still showing dead when I use systemd.

Comment: Is it because you have specified `forking` as the type? Maybe try `Type=oneshot`?

Comment: No onshot I Tried and forking is to let  service wait for data only

Comment: Does your service _actually_ fork to background (daemonize)? It doesn't look like it does. In your PuTTY screenshot it stays in foreground, so Type=forking would not be suitable.